# How to update timestamp as a global variable in Jinja2?

Tags: python, datetime, flask, jinja2

I know that there were similar questions here, but they didn't help me.

In the main `py` file I just set the global variable named `nowts` as follows:

```
app.jinja_env.globals['nowts'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

And in the main (base) template (`base.html` file) I just pass and formatting datetime as follows:

```
{% block navbar %}
... 
<p>{{ nowts.strftime('%A, %b %d %Y / %X') }}</p>
...
{% endblock %}
```

For example, output is:

```
Wednesday, Mar 26 2014 / 11:57:51
```

As you see date and time are displayed correctly, but **only once**. After a few minutes I re-open the main page (or subpages) and the time is still the same. **How to update the `nowts` global variable always if the user refreshes the page?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors) to inject values *per request*:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_template_globals():
    return {
        'nowts': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    }
```

You generally want to use UTC time, not local time, for web servers. You never know where in the world your request comes from.